# How to open only inbuilt calling application in android not skype or other applications

Tags: android, android-intent

```
private void makeCall() {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
   }
}
```

I want to open only phone built call app not Skype or other applications.

Comment: get package of the application you desire and then pass class of that application in the intent instead of defining action

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: I want to open only inbuilt calling application from my app

Comment: you mean triggering  the normal phone call ..???

Comment: yes I want to open only normal phone call app